# Javascript 'iif' equivalent for variable assignment

Tags: variables, declaration, iif

In javascript, how do you declare a variable and set its value to the result of a function in a single line?

In pseudo-code, what I am trying to achieve is this:

```
var coinToss = if(Math.random() < 0.5), assign value of "tail" to my variable, otherwise, assign value of "head" to my variable.
```

I could do this is a block of code, but I assume that there must be a way to achieve the result in a single line?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
var coinToss = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? "tail" : "head";
```

Comment: Hi David, thank you, that's exactly it! ;) Actually easier to answer than to explain! Many thanks for the quick response